# Trying to find a fantasy book with a girl who made her bath boil

Tags: story-identification, witches

I have read this book at least 7 years ago and quite enjoyed it. But i honestly don't remember much about it. I remember it having a woman on the cover of the book, drawn frontal view of head to hips if i remember correctly, I am sure the word "Witch" was in the title. I remember the beginning of the story started with a girl picking apples and then starting her menses, and then somehow starting to make the water in her bath boil. Then the rest of the story gets all jumbled in my brain but I remember enjoying the adventure with a male companion and that some details of the story are traveling through a cave and through a valley of spiders. I think it had a purple cover. Any guesses are appreciated!